# Delphi ListView OnUpdateObjects acces violation problem

Tags: android, delphi

I have a problem with Delphi ListView.

I have a Listview1 with texts and a button. When I click the ListItem Button I fired a trigger (OnButtonClick). After it appears the ListView2, which contains the sublist of a ListView1 Item. I have a toolbar and there is a Back button to navigate back to ListView1 from ListView2. I have an OnUpdateObjects trigger in ListView2 that change color on a TextObjectApperance in ListView2.

The main problem is when I click a ListView1 item button and shows the ListView2 list, then I click the Back button, and after that I click an another ListView1 item button, I get an error message:
First chance exception at $00ABA047. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00aba047: read of address 0x00000084'.

ListView1 buttonclick:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ButtonClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListItem; const AObject: TListItemSimpleControl);
 begin
  GWAHL:=GetWarehouseActivityHeaderList();
  if not Settings.Connected then
    ConnectWMS(GWMS);
  GWHLL:=GetWarehouseActivityLineList(GWAHL[AItem.Index].No);
  GWAH := GWAHL[AItem.Index];
  ShowWAHLineList()
end;
```

Toolbar Speedbutton click:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Visible := true;
  ListView2.Visible := false;
  ToolBar1.Visible := false;
  ShowWAHList();
end;
```

ListView2 OnUpdateObjects:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView2UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  Drawable : TListItemText;
begin
 Drawable := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Quantity'));
 if GWHLL[AItem.Index].QtyToHandle = GWHLL[AItem.Index].Quantity then
  Drawable.TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Darkgreen;
end;
```

Please someone help me, I'm getting desperated!

Comment: An Access Violation near address 0 usually means a nil pointer is being accessed.  Debug your code and find the `nil`.

Comment: The first places to look would be whether `Drawable` or `GWHLL[AItem.Index]` end up being `nil`. I suggest using a temporary variable to store `GWHLL[AItem.Index]` in, and check that for nil (e.g `GWHLLItem := GWHLL[AItem.Index]; if GWHLLItem <> nil then`...) as well as `Drawable`

Comment: @DaveNottage Thanks for your reply. I coded what you suggest, but there are some problems more. As long as I click on a Listitem1 that has more subitems than the previous one, it runs fine, but if I load a longer listview2 and then go back and try to open an another but shorter list, I get an Error message again: Stop in System._UStrEqual procedure: CMP ECX , [EDX - skew] .StrRec.length // Are the string lengths the same? - Access violation
`if GWHLLItem <> nil then
 begin
  if Drawable <> nil then
    if GWHLLItem.QtyToHandle = GWHLLItem.Quantity then
      ...`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're using now